PointPillars Model Debug request
I am working on a project with PointPillars model, I am trying to add a mask to the model that within a specified xyz range, the mask with iterate through all the possible values and output the filtered point cloud. I'm adding the mask to test.py and before I added this mask everything works just fine. I'm using a nested for loop to iterate through all the possible mask values with step value of 0.16, here's the code after I added the mask.
import argparse
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import torch
import pdb

from utils import setup_seed, read_points, read_calib, read_label, \
    keep_bbox_from_image_range, keep_bbox_from_lidar_range, vis_pc, \
    vis_img_3d, bbox3d2corners_camera, points_camera2image, \
    bbox_camera2lidar
from model import PointPillars


def point_range_filter(pts, x_min, x_max, yl, yr, z_max):
    '''
    Applies the XYZ mask to filter points within the given ranges.
    '''
    mask_x = (pts[:, 0] > x_min) & (pts[:, 0] < x_max)
    mask_y_left = pts[:, 1] > yl
    mask_y_right = pts[:, 1] < yr
    mask_z = pts[:, 2] < z_max

    mask = mask_x & mask_y_left & mask_y_right & mask_z
    pts = pts[mask]
    return pts


def main(args):
    CLASSES = {
        'Pedestrian': 0, 
        'Cyclist': 1, 
        'Car': 2
        }
    LABEL2CLASSES = {v:k for k, v in CLASSES.items()}
    pcd_limit_range = np.array([0, -40, -3, 70.4, 40, 0.0], dtype=np.float32)

    if not args.no_cuda:
        model = PointPillars(nclasses=len(CLASSES)).cuda()
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(args.ckpt))
    else:
        model = PointPillars(nclasses=len(CLASSES))
        model.load_state_dict(
            torch.load(args.ckpt, map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
    
    if not os.path.exists(args.pc_path):
        raise FileNotFoundError 
    pc = read_points(args.pc_path)

    x_min, x_max = 0, 69.12
    y_min, y_max = -39.68, 39.68
    z_min, z_max = -3, 1
    step = 0.16

    for x in np.arange(x_min, x_max, step):
        for yl in np.arange(y_min, y_max, step):
            for yr in np.arange(yl + step, y_max, step):
                for z in np.arange(z_min, z_max, step):

                    # Apply the mask to the point cloud
                    filtered_pc = point_range_filter(pc, x, x_max, yl, yr, z)
                    #pc, x, x_max, yl, yr, z(for dynamic mask)
                    #pc, x_min=0, x_max=70.4, yl=-39.68, yr=39.68, z_max=1(for fixed mask)

                    if filtered_pc.size == 0:
                        continue  
                    pc_torch = torch.from_numpy(filtered_pc)

                    if os.path.exists(args.calib_path):
                        calib_info = read_calib(args.calib_path)
                    else:
                        calib_info = None
                    
                    if os.path.exists(args.gt_path):
                        gt_label = read_label(args.gt_path)
                    else:
                        gt_label = None

                    if os.path.exists(args.img_path):
                        img = cv2.imread(args.img_path, 1)
                    else:
                        img = None

                    model.eval()
                    with torch.no_grad():
                        if not args.no_cuda:
                            pc_torch = pc_torch.cuda()
                        
                        result_filter = model(batched_pts=[pc_torch], 
                                            mode='test')[0]

                    if calib_info is not None and img is not None:
                        tr_velo_to_cam = calib_info['Tr_velo_to_cam'].astype(np.float32)
                        r0_rect = calib_info['R0_rect'].astype(np.float32)
                        P2 = calib_info['P2'].astype(np.float32)

                        image_shape = img.shape[:2]
                        result_filter = keep_bbox_from_image_range(result_filter, tr_velo_to_cam, r0_rect, P2, image_shape)

                    result_filter = keep_bbox_from_lidar_range(result_filter, pcd_limit_range)
                    if not result_filter:
                        print("Empty result_filter, skipped")
                        return
                    lidar_bboxes = result_filter['lidar_bboxes']
                    labels, scores = result_filter['labels'], result_filter['scores']

                    vis_pc(filtered_pc, bboxes=lidar_bboxes, labels=labels)

                    if calib_info is not None and img is not None:
                        bboxes2d, camera_bboxes = result_filter['bboxes2d'], result_filter['camera_bboxes'] 
                        bboxes_corners = bbox3d2corners_camera(camera_bboxes)
                        image_points = points_camera2image(bboxes_corners, P2)
                        img = vis_img_3d(img, image_points, labels, rt=True)

                    if calib_info is not None and gt_label is not None:
                        tr_velo_to_cam = calib_info['Tr_velo_to_cam'].astype(np.float32)
                        r0_rect = calib_info['R0_rect'].astype(np.float32)

                        dimensions = gt_label['dimensions']
                        location = gt_label['location']
                        rotation_y = gt_label['rotation_y']
                        gt_labels = np.array([CLASSES.get(item, -1) for item in gt_label['name']])
                        sel = gt_labels != -1
                        gt_labels = gt_labels[sel]
                        bboxes_camera = np.concatenate([location, dimensions, rotation_y[:, None]], axis=-1)
                        gt_lidar_bboxes = bbox_camera2lidar(bboxes_camera, tr_velo_to_cam, r0_rect)
                        bboxes_camera = bboxes_camera[sel]
                        gt_lidar_bboxes = gt_lidar_bboxes[sel]

                        gt_labels = [-1] * len(gt_label['name']) # to distinguish between the ground truth and the predictions
                        
                        pred_gt_lidar_bboxes = np.concatenate([lidar_bboxes, gt_lidar_bboxes], axis=0)
                        pred_gt_labels = np.concatenate([labels, gt_labels])
                        vis_pc(pc, pred_gt_lidar_bboxes, labels=pred_gt_labels)

                        if img is not None:
                            bboxes_corners = bbox3d2corners_camera(bboxes_camera)
                            image_points = points_camera2image(bboxes_corners, P2)
                            gt_labels = [-1] * len(gt_label['name'])
                            img = vis_img_3d(img, image_points, gt_labels, rt=True)
                    
                    if calib_info is not None and img is not None:
                        cv2.imshow(f'{os.path.basename(args.img_path)}-3d bbox', img)
                        cv2.waitKey(0)
            
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Configuration Parameters')
    parser.add_argument('--ckpt', default='pretrained/epoch_160.pth', help='your checkpoint for kitti')
    parser.add_argument('--pc_path', help='your point cloud path')
    parser.add_argument('--calib_path', default='', help='your calib file path')
    parser.add_argument('--gt_path', default='', help='your ground truth path')
    parser.add_argument('--img_path', default='', help='your image path')
    parser.add_argument('--no_cuda', action='store_true',
                        help='whether to use cuda')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args)


but when I tried to run it, it outputs this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 158, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "test.py", line 98, in main
    result_filter = keep_bbox_from_image_range(result_filter, tr_velo_to_cam, r0_rect, P2, image_shape)
  File "C:\Users\1016b\PointPillars\utils\process.py", line 561, in keep_bbox_from_image_range
    lidar_bboxes = result['lidar_bboxes']
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

I know that lidar_bboxes = result['lidar_bboxes'] was not the issue cuz it was from the original code and I did not edit it at all. Can someone help me address what the issue might be?
here is the original pointpillars github link: PointPillars
I figured that it might be because after I added the filter it might generate some empty result and pass it to the "lidar_bboxes" so I added a condition to check if the result_filter is empty, but it did not work, I still got the same issue.
